# Cannot connect Webstorm to FTP project

Tags: ftp, webstorm

I am trying to connect my Webstorm to my web site, so i can work on the files over the network via FTP, but i can't seem to get my FTP connection to work.

If I connect to my website via Filezilla like this :

[image: Filezilla]

... it works perfect.

However when I try with Webstorm nothing seems to work. Here is a screenshot :

[image: Webstorm]

[image]
error :

Note :

- username and password are identical in both cases.
- On webstorm i have tried a number of things for the FTP host: **www.blue-walrus.com, ftp.blue-walrus.com**. And for Web server root URL, i have tried **http://blue-walrus.com**, and http://www.blue-walrus.com.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: can you check if turning 'passive mode' (Deployment/Advanced options) on makes any difference? If it doesn't, please try the following:
1. shut down WebStorm
2. delete the idea.log
3. enable debug logging for 'com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment' category (see http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202 for details)
4. recreate your problem and send the idea.log to Jetbrains support

Comment: **FTP Passive mode** quite likely to be the case here indeed.

Comment: @lena can you please post as proper answer, so i can accept your answer? (yup you were right)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check if turning 'Passive mode' (Deployment/Advanced options) on makes any difference. If it doesn't, please try the following:

- shut down WebStorm
- delete the idea.log
- enable debug logging for 'com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment'
  category (see devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202 for details)
- recreate your problem and send the idea.log to Jetbrains support

Comment: i just needed to turn passive mode on, and it worked